# How do I calculate the derivative of a derivative w.r.t. another derivative?

Tags: derivatives, euler-lagrange-equation

The question is a bit of a mouthful. In Classical Mechanics by Goldstein I have seen the use of the following:

$$ \frac{d\dot{F}}{d\dot{q}_i} = \frac{dF}{dq_i} $$

where $F = F(q_1,q_2,...,q_n;t)$, $ \dot{F} = \frac{dF}{dt} $ and $ \dot{q_i} = \frac{dq_i}{dt} $ . How would I show this?

The use of this result is used on page 17 of the PDF solutions guide (Page 10 within the derivations chapter) by showing that the transformation $L'(q,\dot{q},t) = L(q,\dot{q},t) + \frac{dF(q,t)}{dt}$ keeps the form of the Euler-Lagrange equation invariant:

http://www.slideshare.net/venuatsrr/solution-manual-classical-mechanics-goldstein

Comment: Can you add some context, like a paragraph that uses this identity?  I don't think it's true in all cases.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang When might it not be true?

Comment: @Jam what happens for example in the case ${\mathrm{d}\dot{x}}=0$, say ${\dot{x}}=0$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang It was involved in the substitution of $ L' = L + \frac{dF}{dt}$ into the Euler Lagrange equation $\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}$ to show that the form remains the same.

Comment: @SValera, $\frac{dy}{dt} / \frac{dx}{dt}$ is not$\frac{d\dot{y}}{d\dot{x}}$

Comment: @GCab Actually, it is but that's not what the question's asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this is not true.  For instance, suppose the curve is parametrized by $x=t^2$, $y=t$.  Then
$$
    \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\dot y}{\dot x} = \frac{1}{2t} = \frac{1}{2y}
$$
But $\dot y$ is constant, so
$$
    \frac{d\dot y}{d\dot x} = 0
$$

I looked at your reference, and as far as I can tell, your question is about this statement: If $F = F(q_1,q_2,\dots,q_n;t)$, then
$$
    \frac{\partial \dot F}{\partial \dot q} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial q}
$$
The reason for this is the chain rule.

For each $i$, the expression $\dfrac{\partial \dot F}{\partial \dot q_i}$ stands for $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \dot q_i}\dfrac{dF}{dt}$.  By the chain rule:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{dF}{dt} &= \frac{\partial F}{\partial q_1}\frac{dq_1}{dt}+\dots
                   +\frac{\partial F}{\partial q_n}\frac{dq_n}{dt} 
                   +\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} \\
&=  \frac{\partial F}{\partial q_1}\dot q_1+\dots
                   +\frac{\partial F}{\partial q_n}\dot q_n 
                   +\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} \\
\end{align*}
Then take $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \dot q_i}$ of each side.

Comment: @Matt0410: no problem.  You might want to edit your question now that we know what it really is.